# Prime numbers that are sums of Prime numbers themselves

Tags: prime-numbers

what is the minimum prime number that is the sum of exactly two odd prime numbers?

i.e I want to find a counter example to:

$$p_i+p_j \in \mathbb P \operatorname{iff} i=1 \lor j=1$$

Comment: If prime numbers are allowed to be negative then the answer is $-2=3+(-5)$ for example.

Answer (score 3):

Sum of two odd primes is even, which means that it cannot be a prime > 2.

Comment: lol yeah that's not what people said in the chat room the other day

Comment: haha no its ok fine ill stop trolling